# Invertable rotation of an image

Tags: python, rotation, image-rotation, scikit-image

I am looking for a rotational transform in python, that can be inverted to yield the original image. So far I am using

```
import skimage.transform as tf
import scipy
im = scipy.misc.ascent()
```

[image: Original, unrotated image]

```
r1 = tf.rotate(im, 10, mode='wrap')
```

[image: Image rotated 10 degrees]

```
r2 = tf.rotate(r1, -10, mode='wrap')
```

[image: Rotated Image inversely rotated]

If I do the same using `reflect` the result looks like

[image: Result using 'reflect']

Is there a possibilty to simply rotate an image by `angle` and rotate the result back by `-angle` and end up with the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential solution to your problem would be to use `rotate` with the optional argument `resize` set to `True`, and then to crop the final result.

```
import skimage.transform as tf
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = scipy.misc.ascent()

r1 = tf.rotate(im, 10, mode='wrap', resize=True)
plt.imshow(r1)

r2 = tf.rotate(r1, -10, mode='wrap', resize=True)
plt.imshow(r2)

# Get final image by cropping
imf = r2[int(np.floor((r2.shape[0] - im.shape[0])/2)):int(np.floor((r2.shape[0] + im.shape[0])/2)),int(np.floor((r2.shape[1] - im.shape[1])/2)):int(np.floor((r2.shape[1] + im.shape[1])/2))]

plt.imshow(imf)
```

There will be minor differences between the original and the image rotated twice due to the operations inside the rotation function, but to the eye it looks the same.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Of course the image will be a little different due to interpolation, but this is how it is.